# What is the equivalent of c# syntax analysis in razor?

Tags: .net, razor, syntax, roslyn

I wanted to know if it exists an equivalent of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxTree` for razor or cshtml documents.

My goal is to generate razor document dynamically, and I don't want to do this manually via string concatenation.

I searched for this ability but I only found CSharp and VisualBasic syntax tree available in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis)

Comment: "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" is for analyzing existing code, not generating code - exactly how do you propose to use it to generate razor documents?

Comment: It seems to be possible to generate source code from CSharpSyntaxTree by calling .ToString() method, wright ?